# nodejs memory leak in several cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, v8

1. the raw native tcp server 
   I used a client test code to concurrent long connect the server, and do nothing。
   After 5w conncetions I shut down the client.js, but the server side will have about 100M memory don't release.

the server code ：

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
  console.log('server connected');
  client.on('data',function(){});
  client.on('end',function(){console.log('end');});

});
server.listen(8124, function() {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

the client code:

```
var net = require('net');
var host = '192.168.0.110'
// var host = "localhost"
  , port = 8124


for(var i=0; i < 50000; i++){
  var client = net.connect({host: host, port: port},
      function(i){
       return function() { //'connect' listener
           var num = i;
           console.log('client connected ' + num);
      }}(i)
  );
  client.on('end',function(){
        console.log('end');
        client.end()
  })
}
```

the client is on another machine

2, long loop

```
 var a = b = c = d = [];
 console.log((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'Mb');

 for(i=0;i<50000;i++){
     a.push(new Date());
     b.push(new Date());
     c.push(new Date());
     d.push(new Date());

 }
 console.log((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'Mb');
   a = null;
   b = null;
   c = null;
   d = null;

 console.log('null');
 console.log((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'Mb');

 console.log((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'Mb');
 setInterval(function(){
   console.log((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'Mb');
 },5000);
```

I set the variable to null but the memory does not release.
somebody tell me to use process.nextTick to prevent long loop
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are trying to do the stress on server or you want to know what happened to your server if reached 50k concurrent server? What @miktam said is correct, you have to wait the GC to clear the momory. If your server really reached 50 k concurrent users, i recommend you to scale out your server to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Memory is not released immediately after you deallocate the reference and set it to null. If you want to force GC to be executed in a given moment:

1. start node with --expose-gc

`node --expose-gc test.js`

1. in your code add invocation of gc:

`global.gc();`

You shall not do this in production, as V8 is handling GC invocation by itself and is very good in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your client js:

```
client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
    client.end()
})
```

This event will happen *after* the connection ends, which you do by calling `.end()`... so it doesn't make any sense to call `.end()` in the end event. Also, you are not closing the connection at all:

```
var client = net.connect({
    host: host,
    port: port
}, function(i) {
    return function() { //'connect' listener
        var num = i;
        console.log('client connected ' + num);
        this.end() //Close the connection
    }
}(i));
```

After fixing that I can run your code without exceptions, and it did not leak for me.

Server code:

```
function getUsed() {
    return process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
}
var startedWith;
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
    client.on('data', function() {});
    client.on('end', function() {
        console.log("end");
    });
});
server.listen(8124, function() {
    startedWith = getUsed();
});
setInterval(function() {
    gc();
}, 13);
setInterval(function() {
    gc();
    console.log(getUsed() - startedWith);
}, 250)
```

Run with node 0.10 `$ node --expose-gc server.js`

Client code:

```
var net = require('net');
var host = 'localhost',
    port = 8124
for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
    var client = net.connect({
        host: host,
        port: port
    },

    function(i) {
        return function() { //'connect' listener
            var num = i;
            console.log('client connected ' + num);
            this.end();
        }
    }(i));
    client.on('end', function() {
        console.log('end');
    })
}
```

Run with node 0.10 `$ node client.js` after server is running.

Comment: because you use the gc() . and have you ever try just use the setInterval()? the memory  that used more and more!

Comment: @vagabond of course I use `gc()`, otherwise I'd have to wait longer to see results.

Comment: oh I am sorry @Esailija, I misunderstand the gc() command.  yes, the v8 default gc is very  inactive。

Comment: @vagabond `gc()` will not release memory if that memory woulnd't have been released via normal gc eventually..

Comment: thanks @Esailija do you have any more information about how v8 gc ? where do you learn the v8